# How to delete a node from linked list in cpp from the memory permanantly,

Tags: c++, linked-list

Here is my code i have written. Whats wrong in it. Every time i delete nodes from starting to end its going fine but when deleting randomly its breaking the program.

I have to delete the nodes from the heap/memory permanently not just breaking the links between them.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node 
{
    private:
        int data;
        Node *next;
    public:
        Node(){}
        Node(int d) 
        {
            data = d;
            next = NULL;
        }
        void SetNext(Node *nextNode) 
        {
            next = nextNode;
        }
        int Data() 
        {

            return data;
        }
        Node* Next() 
        {
            return next;
        }
};

class List 
{
    Node *head;
  public:
    List() { head = NULL; };

    void Insert(int d)
    {
        int value;
        value = d;

        Node* n1 = new Node(value);
        n1->SetNext(NULL);

        Node *temp = head;

        if(temp != NULL)
        {
            while(temp->Next() != NULL)
            {
                temp = temp->Next();
            }
            temp->SetNext(n1);
        }
        else
            head = n1;
    };

    void Delete()
    {
        int value;
        cout<<"enter a value to Delete"<<endl;
        cin>>value;

        Node* temp;
        temp = head;
        Node *prev;

        if(temp == NULL)
        {
            cout<<"List is empty, deletion is not possible"<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            if(temp->Next() == NULL)
            {
                if(temp->Data() == value)
                {
                    delete temp;
                    head = NULL;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout<<"Entered Data value is not available in the List"<<endl;
                }
            }
            else if((temp->Data() == value))
            {
                head = temp->Next();
                delete temp;
            }
            else
            {
                while(temp->Next() != NULL)
                {
                    prev = temp;
                    temp = temp->Next();
                    if((temp->Data() == value) && (temp->Next() != NULL))
                    {
                        prev->SetNext(temp->Next());
                        delete temp;
                    }
                    else if(temp->Data() == value && temp->Next() == NULL)
                    {
                        prev->SetNext(NULL);
                        delete temp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    void Print()
    {
        Node *temp = head;

        if ( temp == NULL ) 
        {
            cout << "EMPTY" << endl;
            return;
        }

        if ( temp->Next() == NULL ) 
        {
            cout << temp->Data();
            cout << " --> ";
            cout << "NULL" << endl;
        }
        else 
        {
            do
            {
                cout << temp->Data();
                cout << " --> ";
                temp = temp->Next();
            }
            while ( temp != NULL );
            cout << "NULL" << endl;
        }
    };

    void isEmpty()
    {
        if(head == NULL)
            cout<<"List is Empty"<<endl;
        else
            cout<<"List is not Empty"<<endl;
    };

};


int main()
{
    List l1;
    char ch;
    do
    {
        cout<<"\n Linked List "<<endl;
        cout<<"I. Insert \t D. Delete"<<endl;
        cout<<"P. Print \t E. isEmpty \t X.EXIT"<<endl;

        cout<<"Enter Your Choice :"<<endl;
        cin>>ch;

        if((ch>=97)&&(ch<=122))
        {
            ch=ch-32;
        }

        switch(ch)
        {
            case 'I': int value;
                      cout<<"\n***** Inserting *****"<<endl;
                      cout<<"enter a value to insert"<<endl;
                      cin>>value;
                    l1.Insert(value);
                    break;

            case 'D':   cout<<"\n***** Delete *****"<<endl;
                    l1.Print();
                    cout<<"\nDelete any value from the above listed"<<endl;
                    l1.Delete();
                    system("pause");
                    break;

            case 'P':   cout<<"\n***** Print *****"<<endl;
                    l1.Print();
                    system("pause");
                    break;

            case 'E': cout<<"\n***** isEmpty *****"<<endl;
                    l1.isEmpty();
                    system("pause");
                    break;

            case 'X': exit(1);
                    break;
            default: cout<<"\n Invalid Choice"<<endl;

        }
        system("cls");
    }
    while(1);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please read the help center and come back with a better question, this one will probably be closed as off topic.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Delete()` function is overly complicated.  It can be greatly simplified.  For that matter, most of your `List` code can be simplified.  Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Node 
{
private:
    int data;
    Node *next;

public:
    Node(int d = 0) : data(d), next(NULL) {}

    void SetNext(Node *nextNode) 
    {
        next = nextNode;
    }

    int Data() const
    {
        return data;
    }

    Node* Next() const
    {
        return next;
    }
};

class List 
{
private:
    Node *head;
    Node *tail;

public:
    List() : head(NULL), tail(NULL) {}
    ~List() { Clear(); }

    void Clear()
    {
        Node *temp = head;
        Node *next;

        head = tail = NULL;

        while ( temp != NULL )
        {
            next = temp->Next();
            delete temp;
            temp = next;
        }
    }

    void Insert(int d)
    {
        Node* n1 = new Node(d);

        if ( head == NULL )
            head = n1;

        if ( tail != NULL )
            tail->SetNext(n1);

        tail = n1;
    }

    bool Delete(int value)
    {
        Node* temp = head;
        Node *prev = NULL;

        while ( temp != NULL )
        {
            Node* next = temp->Next();

            if ( temp->Data() == value )
            {
                if( prev != NULL )
                    prev->SetNext(next);

                if( head == temp )
                    head = next;

                if( tail == temp )
                    tail = prev;

                delete temp;

                return true;
            }

            prev = temp;
            temp = next;
        }

        return false;
    }

    void Print() const
    {
        Node *temp = head;

        if ( temp == NULL ) 
        {
            cout << "EMPTY" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            do
            {
                cout << temp->Data() << " --> ";
                temp = temp->Next();
            }
            while ( temp != NULL );

            cout << " NULL" << endl;
        }
    }

    bool isEmpty() const
    {
        return (head == NULL);
    }
};

int main()
{
    List l1;
    char ch;

    do
    {
        cout << "\n Linked List " < <endl;
        cout << "I. Insert \t D. Delete \t C. Clear" << endl;
        cout << "P. Print \t E. isEmpty \t X. EXIT" << endl;

        cout << "Enter Your Choice :" << endl;
        cin >> ch;

        if ( (ch >= 'a') && (ch <= 'z') )
        {
            ch -= 32;
        }

        switch (ch)
        {
            case 'I':
            {
                int value;
                cout << "\n***** Inserting *****" << endl;
                cout << "enter a number to insert" << endl;
                if ( cin >> value )
                    l1.Insert(value);
                else
                {
                    cout << "\nYou did not enter a valid number" << endl;
                    system("pause");
                }
                break;
            }

            case 'D':
            {
                cout << "\n***** Delete *****" << endl;

                if ( l1.isEmpty() )
                {
                    cout << "List is empty, deletion is not possible" << endl;
                    break;
                }

                l1.Print();
                cout << "\nDelete any number from the above list" << endl;

                int value;
                cout << "enter a number to delete" << endl;
                if ( cin >> value )
                {
                    if ( l1.Delete(value) )
                        cout << "Entered number has been deleted from the List" << endl;
                    else
                        cout << "Entered number is not available in the List" << endl;
                }
                else
                    cout << "\nYou did not enter a valid number" << endl;
                system("pause");
                break;
            }

            case 'C':
            {
                cout << "\n***** Clear *****" << endl;
                l1.Clear();
                cout << "List is now empty" << endl;
                system("pause");
                break;
            }

            case 'P':
            {
                cout << "\n***** Print *****" << endl;
                l1.Print();
                system("pause");
                break;
            }

            case 'E':
            {
                cout << "\n***** isEmpty *****" << endl;
                if ( l1.isEmpty() )
                    cout << "List is Empty" << endl;
                else
                    cout << "List is not Empty" << endl;
                system("pause");
                break;
            }

            case 'X':
                exit(1);
                break;

            default:
                cout << "\n Invalid Choice" << endl;
                system("pause");
                break;
        }

        system("cls");
    }
    while (1);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

With that said, you really should be using the [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) class instead, or even the [`std::forward_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list) class in C++11 and later.  Let the STL manage the nodes for you, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class List 
{
private:
    list<int> l;

public:
    void Clear()
    {
        l.clear();
    }

    void Insert(int d)
    {
        l.push_back(d);
    }

    bool Delete(int value)
    {
        list<int>::iterator iter = find(l.begin(), l.end(), value);
        if( iter != l.end() )
        {
            l.erase(iter);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    void Print() const
    {
        if ( l.empty() ) 
        {
            cout << "EMPTY" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            list<int>::iterator iter = l.begin();
            do
            {
                cout << *iter << " --> ";
            }
            while ( ++iter != l.end() );

            cout << " NULL" << endl;
        }
    }

    bool isEmpty() const
    {
        return l.empty();
    }
};
```

Comment: I was going to say the same, but I am too slow. Also the testing can be simplified. It's frustrating to enter data each time for testing the linked list part.

Comment: Um, so the list data can be cleared? I don't understand the question. What good is a list if it cannot remove its nodes from memory on demand?